# Using peered GPUs in a single stream

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

In my current project I use GPUs for signal processing and visualization. I'm already using streams to allow for asynchronous operation. The signal is processed in *frames* and for each frame the processing steps in a stream are as following

1. memcpy to device
2. signal conditioning
3. image processing
4. visualization

Right now the steps are happening on a single GPU, however my machine has a Multi-GPU card (GeForce GTX 690) and I'd like to distribute the operation between the two devices. Basically I'd like to perform steps 1 and 2 on device *A* and steps 3 and 4 on device *B*, while the operations 1, 2, 3 and 4 are still executed as a single asynchronous stream. The desired outcome is a streaming layout that looks like this

```
Device A Stream a 1 2       1 2  ...
         Stream b      1 2  ...
Device B Stream a    3 4       3 4 ...
         Stream b         3 4  ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: My answer below is wrong and does not work.  [Streams are associated with the devices they were created on](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multi-device-system).  You cannot have a single stream issuing kernels or memcopies to two different devices.  I will delete my incorrect answer below shortly.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for the heads up. The very same document also states, that `cudaStreamWaitEvent` can be used for inter-device synchronization. So by using 2*n streams it should be possible to synchronize the per-device streams asynchronously. Right now I'm refactoring the code in question, but I'll try this as soon as the thing works again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous attempt was not correct, because a stream is associated with the device it was created on.  So I think the most direct answer to your question as posed in the title is "it can't be done".  You cannot create a single stream and issue commands to more than one GPU from it.  From [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multi-device-system):

```
Stream and Event Behavior

A kernel launch or memory copy will fail if it is issued to a stream that is not associated to the current device
```

However while researching it, I noted that events are a suggested way to synchronize two streams on two different devices:

> `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` will succeed even if the input stream and input
>   event are associated to different devices. cudaStreamWaitEvent() can
>   therefore be used to synchronize multiple devices with each other.

So in that vein, I created the following code to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 32
#define K1VAL 5
#define K3VAL 3

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


__global__ void kernel1(int *frame, int size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);

  if (idx == 0){
   int *a = new int[10000]; // just to make this kernel take a while
   for (int i = 0; i<10000; i++)
     a[i] = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     frame[i] += K1VAL;
   }
}


__global__ void kernel3(int *frame, int size){

  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
  if (idx == 0)
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     frame[i] -= K3VAL;
}

void set_device(int dev){
  int ldev;
  cudaSetDevice(dev);
  cudaGetDevice(&ldev);
  cudaCheckErrors("set device error");
  if (ldev != dev){
    printf("set device mismatch error\n");
    exit(1);
    }
}


int main(){

  int A=0;
  int B=1;
  int framesize = SIZE*sizeof(int);
  int *h_frame;
  int *d_frame_aA,  *d_frame_bB;
  int numdev = 0;
  cudaGetDeviceCount(&numdev);
  cudaCheckErrors("can't determine number of devices");
  if (numdev < 2){
   printf("not enough devices!\n");
   return 1;
   }
  set_device(A);
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_frame_aA, framesize);  // stream_a
  cudaMemset(d_frame_aA, 0, framesize);
  set_device(B);
  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_frame_bB, framesize);  // stream_b
  cudaMemset(d_frame_bB, 0, framesize);
  cudaHostAlloc((void **) &h_frame, framesize, cudaHostAllocDefault);
  cudaCheckErrors("allocations failure");

  set_device(A);
  cudaStream_t stream_a, stream_b;
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream_a);
  cudaEvent_t absync;
  cudaEventCreate(&absync);
  set_device(B);
  cudaStreamCreate(&stream_b);
  cudaCheckErrors("stream creation failure");


  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    h_frame[i] = 0;

  set_device(A);
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(B, 0);
  set_device(B);
  cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(A, 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("enable peer access fail");


  set_device(A);
  cudaMemcpyAsync(d_frame_aA, h_frame, framesize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream_a);
  kernel1<<<1,1,0, stream_a>>>(d_frame_aA, SIZE);
  cudaCheckErrors("kernel1 fail");
  cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(d_frame_bB, B, d_frame_aA, A, framesize, stream_a );
  cudaCheckErrors("memcpypeer fail");
  cudaEventRecord(absync, stream_a);
  set_device(B);
  // comment out the next line to see the failure
  cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream_b, absync, 0);
  kernel3<<<1,1,0, stream_b>>>(d_frame_bB, SIZE);
  cudaCheckErrors("main sequence fail");


//  cudaCheckErrors("main sequence failure");

  cudaMemcpy(h_frame, d_frame_bB, framesize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("results_a memcpy fail");
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    if (h_frame[i] != (K1VAL - K3VAL)) {
      printf("results error\n");
      return 1;
      }
  printf("success\n");
  return 0;

}
```

If you run the code as-is, you should get a `success` message.
If you comment out the line that forces stream b (on Device B) to wait on stream a (on Device A), then you'll see a `results error` message.  So this demonstrates how to sync a stream on one device to a stream on another.  Hope it helps.  Sorry for the confusion on the first go-round.

Comment: This is actually very close to what I already tried, with the only difference that I didn't use `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync` to transfer data between GPUs. I was under the impression that by using `cudaEnablePeerAccess` a device could directly memory of its peers without going through a copy. Anyway, the result was, that, according to *nvvp*, all operations were carried out on device A; when running in the profiler the visualization part is disabled and I collect just statistics about the result.

Comment: You got the kernel and function setup right, but there will likely be a 5th kernel execution, a cudaMemcpy device-to-host for retrieving the result of step/kernel 3, so that it can be stored for offline analysis and visualization.

Comment: Is not Peer access only available on the tesla series? as noted in the text you linked "devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher from the Tesla series may address each other’s memory"

Comment: @ks6g10 after answering that question, I had a colleague tell me anecdotally that *hi speed* peer access seemed to work on GTX690. Even if *hi speed* peer access does not work, the `cudaMemcpyPeerAsync()` call will still work, it will just take place at a slightly slower rate because it is being staged through system memory.  You may wish to read the relevant section I linked in that answer.

Comment: @ks6g10: According to documentation it's available for Kepler as well. I do not mind that extra copy operation, given the fact that I'm PCI-E bandwidth bound anyway.

Comment: I've just updated my posting with tested code that I believe demonstrates something that could be useful.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Yes, I was thinking about the very same scheme. I still need to test it with my application, but I think this looks good.

Answer (score 1):

`cudaStreamWaitEvent()` enables inter-GPU synchronization, since you can insert a wait on a CUDA event belonging to another device.

So what you need for inter-GPU synchronization between the producer and the consumer is to allocate a few events (at least 2) for each of the 2 GPUs, then have the producer `cudaEventRecord()` and the consumer `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` on the same event.  `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` inserts a command into the current device's command buffer that causes it to suspend execution until the given event has been recorded.

Below see a code fragment where a peer-to-peer memcpy is implemented using `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` in this way.  Once the pump is primed, the producer and consumer should both be doing PCIe transfers concurrently, each to one of the two staging buffers (which are allocated in portable pinned memory).

```
cudaError_t
chMemcpyPeerToPeer( 
    void *_dst, int dstDevice, 
    const void *_src, int srcDevice, 
    size_t N ) 
{
    cudaError_t status;
    char *dst = (char *) _dst;
    const char *src = (const char *) _src;
    int stagingIndex = 0;
    while ( N ) {
        size_t thisCopySize = min( N, STAGING_BUFFER_SIZE );

        CUDART_CHECK( cudaSetDevice( srcDevice ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaStreamWaitEvent( NULL, g_events[dstDevice][stagingIndex], 0 ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaMemcpyAsync( g_hostBuffers[stagingIndex], src, thisCopySize, 
            cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, NULL ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaEventRecord( g_events[srcDevice][stagingIndex] ) );

        CUDART_CHECK( cudaSetDevice( dstDevice ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaStreamWaitEvent( NULL, g_events[srcDevice][stagingIndex], 0 ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaMemcpyAsync( dst, g_hostBuffers[stagingIndex], thisCopySize, 
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, NULL ) );
        CUDART_CHECK( cudaEventRecord( g_events[dstDevice][stagingIndex] ) );

        dst += thisCopySize;
        src += thisCopySize;
        N -= thisCopySize;
        stagingIndex = 1 - stagingIndex;
    }
    // Wait until both devices are done
    CUDART_CHECK( cudaSetDevice( srcDevice ) );
    CUDART_CHECK( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    CUDART_CHECK( cudaSetDevice( dstDevice ) );
    CUDART_CHECK( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

Error:
    return status;
}
```

Full source code in https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/blob/master/memory/peer2peerMemcpy.cu