# whose stream should be used for Unified Virtual Address (UVA) copy between GPUs?

Tags: cuda

so if i want do Unified Virtual Address (UVA) copy between two GPUs (using cudaMemcpyAsync with kind argument is cudaMemcopyDefault), whose stream should I use? stream of device of the source memory? or stream of dev of the destined memory?

thank you

Comment: Neither. Use the stream which is  defined in the active context. If you are in the source memory context, use the source stream. If you are in the destination context, use the destination stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: use [cudaMemcpyPeerAsync](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g8ff91443cbf4bb9334bec897ac7d6691) instead.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263986/using-peered-gpus-in-a-single-stream/14264899#14264899) as an example.

I guess to answer your question, [from here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution):

> Stream and Event Behavior
>
> A kernel launch or memory copy will fail if it is issued to a stream
>   that is not associated to the current device

So choose a stream that corresponds to the device that corresponds to the most recent `cudaSetDevice()` call that you made.